# Infinispan tree like cache structure

Tags: caching, jboss, tree, structure, infinispan

I would like to use Infinispan following a tree like structure for the cache.  For example, using the following data structure for ticker symbols:

1. Exchange (NY stock exchange, AMEX...)
2. Date
3. Ticker

I am not sure how to implement this as the only examples that I have found are pretty basic such as:

```
cache.put("key", "value");
```

I tried to look up the internet and stackoverflow without any luck...  I know that I could flatten the structure in the example above but for illustrative purposes, I would like to know how Infinispan works (and the tutorials don't cover it, which is why I must not be thinking about it correctly since Infinispan is pretty robust).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Julien

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you check the [tree module](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Tree+API+Module) in Infinispan?